# Printing value of a cell in openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I was writing a simple python program using `openpyxl` and I'm just a beginner trying to learn more about python and it's modules as it's confusing.

I wanted to print the value of a cell and I eventually landed at the doc page

https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.cell.cell.html?highlight=value#openpyxl.cell.cell.Cell.value

I would simply like to know what

```
class openpyxl.cell.cell.Cell(worksheet, row=None, column=None, value=None, style_array=None)
```

actually means over here. I know it says `openpyxl.cell.cell` module at the top but really I find it confusing, does this mean that this is a class in a module in a module or have I got it entirely wrong?

Right now I'm using code like:

```
import openpyxl as xl
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = xl.load_workbook('xyz.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']
print(ws.cell(row=1,column=1).value})
```

My question is how does the last line even work? Shouldn't I use `xl.cell.cell.value` instead of `ws.cell(row=1,column=1).value`? I'm sorry but I don't understand. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: if your code work then why to change ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
import openpyxl 
print( openpyxl.__file__ )
```

to find path to source code (skip `__init__.py`)

On Linux I have `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/openpyxl/` and there is folder `cell` with file `cell.py` which has `class Cell` - and this is your `class openpyxl.cell.cell.Cell`

---

There is no

```
xl.cell.cell.value
```

but

```
xl.cell.cell.Cell(...).value
```

or

```
mycell = xl.cell.cell.Cell(...) 
mycell.value
```

but this creates standalone `cell` which is not part of `workspace` so it is useless for you.

When you read file then it creates many `Cell()` and keep all of them in other class `Workspace` (maybe as list/dict of cells or array of cells) and `Workspace` has method `cell(row,column)` (it is not `class Cell`, nor module `cell`) to give you access to one of `Cell()`.

So use

```
ws.cell(row=1,column=1).value
```

because it gives you access to cells readed from file.

Doc can be useful to see what other functions you can use with `ws.cell(row=1,column=1)` - ie

```
mycell = ws.cell(row=1,column=1)

print( mycell.value )
print( mycell.column_letter )
print( mycell.column )
print( mycell.row )
print( mycell.offset(row=1,column=1) )
```

Comment: Ok so when you say `xl.cell.cell.value` we mean that in the xl module, there's a folder `cell` and in that folder `cell` there's a file called `cell.py` and `Cell` is a class of `cell.py`?

Comment: `xl.cell.cell.value` doesn't exist in module `openpyyxl`. There is `openpyxl.cell.cell.Cell` and it is module/folder: `openpyxl`, submodule/subfolder: `cell`, submodule/file: `cell.py`, class: `Cell`